# Regular expression to match a regular expression inside square brackets

Tags: regex

I have a string that contains a regular expression within square brackets, and can contain more than 1 item inside square brackets.  below is an example of a string I'm using:

```
[REGEX:^([0-9])*$][REGEXERROR:That value is not valid]
```

In the example above, I'd like to match for the item `[REGEX:^([0-9])*$]`, but I can't figure out how.

I thought I'd try using the regular expression `\[REGEX:.*?\]`, but it matches `[REGEX:^([0-9]` (ie; it finishes when it finds the first `]`).

I also tried `\[REGEX:.*\]`, but it matches everything right to the end of the string.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there any chance the regex could use delimiters?  If we knew you would always have `^[..]$` or `/expression/`, it would be much easier.

Comment: Try to match `\[REGEX:[\S]*\]`

Comment: Thanks !\[REGEX:[\S]*\] worked (although I have no idea how/why)

Comment: `\s` matches whitespace characters, capitalizing makes it the opposite.  So this would fail if you had a pattern like [`[REGEX:^foo bar$]`](http://regex101.com/r/tF2sC4).

Comment: Try this: `\[REGEX:[^\[]*(\[[^\]]*\][^\[]*)*\]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you are using PCRE, this should be able to find nested brackets in regular expressions:

`\[REGEX:[^\[]*(\[[^\]]*\][^\[]*)*\]`

This technique is called *unrolling*. The basic idea of this regex is:

1. match the starting brackets
2. match all characters that are not brackets
3. match one brackets
4. match all trailing characters that are not brackets
5. then repeat 3 and 4 until the last closing bracket comes

Explanation with free-space:

```
\[              # start brackets
   REGEX:       # plain match 
   [^\[]*       # match any symbols other than [
   (            # then match nested brackets  
     \[         # the start [ of nested
     [^\]]*     # anything inside the bracket
     \]         # closing bracket 
     [^\[]*     # trailing symbols after brackets
   )*           # repeatable  
\]              # end brackets
```

Reference: [Mastering Regular Expression](http://books.google.com/books?id=sshKXlr32-AC&pg=PA272&lpg=PA272&dq=regular%20expression%20unrolling&source=bl&ots=d9T1ZU6gFk&sig=_LnpRcjPFJMjz0ZuulS5fX5vj_Y&hl=en&sa=X&ei=A1hHU9c-jITyBci1gaAD#v=onepage&q=regular%20expression%20unrolling&f=false)

Comment: This solution works, however, the solution provided by hjpotter92 (\\[REGEX:[\S]*\\]) also works and looks less complicated.  Is there any advantage of one over the other?

Comment: @MattEno Yes, because the original one cannot handle space in regex nor error message without space. Example: http://regex101.com/r/oE1pC7